# Bluetooth/WiFi Direct suport on Firebase Testlab / other testbed

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi-direct, firebase-test-lab

I want to run some tests to check Bluetooth/WiFi Direct connectivity on Firebase Testlab. Is it possible? I'd need two devices being in proximity to establish a connection.

If not, is there any other testbed allowing to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got an official answer from Google support. Bluetooth/WiFi Direct communication is not supported.

It's currently a feature request, but without any specific timeline.